# how to count postgresql user login

Tags: postgresql, config, postgresql-13

I am trying to find out total number of postgresql users login details in month but I am not able to find. I have checked pg_stat_activity table and other tables as well but not getting the details

```
select count(*) as session_count 
from (
   select sess_id 
   from pg_stat_activity 
   group by sess_id
) as activity;
```

while using this query I am getting sess_id does not exist.
I am using postgresql 13

Answer (score 0):

there is no audit trail in the open source version of Postgres ... you can either use the EDB version or write your own plugin ..

this might help you with "your own plugin" way ...

https://github.com/splendiddata/login_hook

TLDR:

- You have to download and compile the plugin
- Create the extension
- then use this code

  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION login_hook.login() RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $$
  DECLARE
  ex_state   TEXT;
  ex_message TEXT;
  ex_detail  TEXT;
  ex_hint    TEXT;
  ex_context TEXT;
  BEGIN
  IF NOT login_hook.is_executing_login_hook()
  THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'The login_hook.login() function should only be invoked by the login_hook code';
  END IF;

  ```
   BEGIN
      -- 
      -- Do whatever you need to do at login here.
      -- For example:
      RAISE NOTICE 'Hello %', current_user;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
          GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS ex_state   = RETURNED_SQLSTATE
                                , ex_message = MESSAGE_TEXT
                                , ex_detail  = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
                                , ex_hint    = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT
                                , ex_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
          RAISE LOG e'Error in login_hook.login()\nsqlstate: %\nmessage : %\ndetail  : %\nhint    : %\ncontext : %'
                  , ex_state
                  , ex_message
                  , ex_detail
                  , ex_hint
                  , ex_context;
   END ;
  ```

  END
  $$;
  GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION login_hook.login() TO PUBLIC;

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `log_connections`, then you will find the information in the log file.

If you set `log_destination = csvlog`, the log will be written in CSV format, which you can load into a table (or define as an external table using `file_fdw`) and run queries on it.

Comment: I have done by creating a new table but I am looking for log automation dumping into table. I am doing it manually now to check and that is not so good for auditing.

Comment: Use `cron` or something similar.